# Instance method is not working from an object while it works perefctly from its class

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

This is the most strange error that I got since I started to program with Python years ago.

First, theses are my classes (Sorry for the long code):

```
class Quran(Iterable):

    def __init__(self):
        self.sourats = []

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        # There is some code here
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, sourat_num):
        if not (isinstance(sourat_num, int) or isinstance(sourat_num, slice)):
            raise TypeError('Indexing Quran can be done only using ints or slices')
        if isinstance(sourat_num, int):
            sourat_num -= 1
        else:
            sourat_num = slice(sourat_num.start - 1, sourat_num.stop)
        try:
            return self.sourats[sourat_num]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sourats)

    # Other methods ...

class Sourat(Iterable):

    sourats_titles = [ # 114 strs here
    ]

    def __init__(self, number, quran):
        if not isinstance(number, int):
            raise TypeError('number must be int')
        if not isinstance(quran, Quran):
            raise TypeError('quran must be Quran')
        self.num = number
        self.ayats = []
        self.quran = quran

    def __int__(self):
        return self.num

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        # Some code here
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, ayat_num):
        if not (isinstance(ayat_num, int) or isinstance(ayat_num, slice)):
            raise TypeError('Indexing Sourat can be done only using ints or slices')
        if isinstance(ayat_num, int):
            ayat_num -= 1
        else:
            ayat_num = slice(ayat_num.start-1, ayat_num.stop)
        try:
            return self.ayats[ayat_num]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.ayats)

    def location(self):
        return self.num

    def previous(self):
        p_num = self.num-1
        if p_num < 1:
            return None
        return self.quran[p_num]

    def next(self):
        n_num = self.num+1
        if n_num > len(self.quran):
            return None
        return self.quran[n_num]

    # Other methods ...

class Word(Iterable):

    def __init__(self, number, text, features, ayat):
        if not isinstance(number, int):
            raise TypeError('number must be int')
        if not isinstance(text, str):
            raise TypeError('text must be str')
        if not (isinstance(features, dict) and features['type'] in ('PREFIX', 'STEM', 'SUFFIX')):
            raise TypeError('features[type] must be one of PREFIX, STEM, SUFFIX')
        if not isinstance(ayat, Ayat):
            raise TypeError('ayat must be Ayat')
        self.num = number
        self.text = text
        self.root = features.get('ROOT', None)
        self.lem = features.get('LEM', None)
        self.type = features['type']
        self.next = None
        self.previous = None
        self.ayat = ayat

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        # Some code here

    def __hash__(self):
        # Some code here
        pass

    def previous(self):
        p_num = self.num-1
        if p_num < 1:
            previous_ayat = self.ayat.previous()
            if previous_ayat:
                return previous_ayat[-1]
            else:
                return None
        return self.ayat[p_num]

    def next(self):
        n_num = self.num+1
        if n_num > len(self.ayat):
            next_ayat = self.ayat.next()
            if next_ayat:
                return next_ayat[0]
            else:
                return None
        return self.ayat[n_num]

        # Other methods ...
```

And this is what I am have in the main code :

```
quran_last_14_sourats = parse_quranic_corpus('quranic-corpus-morphology-0.4-last-14-sourats.txt')
sourat = quran_last_14_sourats[2]
ayat = sourat[2]
word = ayat[1]
assert isinstance(ayat, Ayat)
assert isinstance(word, Word)
print(ayat.previous())
print(ayat)
print(ayat.next())
print(Word.next(word))  # This works !!!
print(word.next())  # This doesn't work !!!
```

My problem is in the `next(self)` and `previous(self)` in the class `Word`, everything else works perfectly.

When I try to use `word.next()` or `word.previous()`, it complains that `NoneType is not callable`. I tried to `print(word.next)` and it showed `None`, but this is not logical because these two methods are inside the class `Word`. This problem doesn't happen in classes `Sourat` and `Ayat` even that they have the same structure. And the most crazy thing is that `Word.next(word)` works without any problem !

Is this a bug in Python 3 ? (BTW I am using the latest version: 3.5.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bug in Python 3 ?

In a word, no.

Instance members and instance methods share the same namespace. Thus, your line in `Word.__init__()`:

```
self.next = None
```

obliterates the reference to the method `Word.next()` inside the newly-allocated `Word` object.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I have just noticed that, thanks !

Comment: No forgiveness required. You asked a legitimate question; everyone here is happy to answer those. Just remember to vote and accept. In future, however, please read [mcve] and apply those techniques before posting a question. I suspect that you would have found your own error if you had distilled your code to the minimal complete example.